# Is it possible to define a variable for only a specific iOS version in Swift? On the class level

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to achieve this on the Class level of an object? Specifically looking at this to have an app containing WatchConnectivity but also suppporting iOS8

```
class Test {
    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        let session: WCSession ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a computed `static` property:

```
public class Example {  
  public static var answerToEverything: Int {
    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
      return 42
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }
}
```

Or, you can consider using `@available` attribute instead:

```
public class Example {
  @available(iOS, introduced=1.0)
  public static var answerToEverything: Int = 42
}
```

where `1.0` is the version of *your library* (not iOS).

This would be useful if you're more concerned about  making sure it's used *on iOS* and less concerned about the iOS version.

Comment: As long as you don't test for the mere *existence* of the property to determine what version number you're running.

Comment: @NRitH +1: Yes, definitely don't reinvent `#available` here with such a property...! ;]

Comment: Awesome that works. Yea will stick with the `@available` attribute then

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap it with a **computed property**, for instance for `UIMenu`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
var menu: UIMenu? { // use this as a getter for what you want
   return _menu as? UIMenu
}
var _menu: Any? // use this reference as a setter for what you want
```